# How can I know because myapplication crash?

Tags: cocoa

Where XCode generate error for application crash ?
I'm crazyng ! My application when open second file xib with webview then it crash. But I don't know why ? how can i Know where is error ?

Comment: your english is vary bad... i can't understand, your application project crash or your application on device crash???

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use the debugger in Xcode.

Run your app under the debugger then instead if simply getting a stack trace Xcode will stop at the line the fault occurs and show you your code and variables. You can then examine the contents of your variables, the call tree, etc. and hunt down the problem.

Once you know the general area of the problem you can place breakpoints to pause your application before the problem occurs and check whether your variables have the values expected etc. Then you can run till the next breakpoint, or step through your code a line at a time.

You can add code, such as `NSAssert`'s and `NSLog`'s to your app to check progress and display information without stopping the run, etc.

It's a process, and some problems will be harder to track down, but you'll get quicker at it with practice.

The Xcode documentation will tell you all about the debugger.

HTH